# Python UDP request hanging

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, udp

I have the following code which sends a bit of data via UDP to the local host and requests some data back. However, every time I run the program it hangs on line 25 but I don't know why. Since I only specify buffer size I assume that `recvfrom()` gets data from whichever it had sent it to but I am getting no response.

```
 2 import socket
 13 
 14 target_host = "127.0.0.1" #  localhost
 15 target_port = 80          #  http port
 16 
 17 #  create a socket object using IPv4 & UDP
 18 client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
 19 
 20 #  send some data
 21 client.sendto(b"AAAABBBCC", (target_host, target_port))
 22 
 23 
 24 #  receive some data
 25 data, addr = client.recvfrom(4096)
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting a packet back? Virtually all HTTP servers use TCP, not UDP. Instead of localhost:80, you can try starting an interactive server, for example with netcat: `nc -l -u -p 1234`, where 1234 is the port you want.

Comment: I'm not sure I am getting a packet back. I guess I could pull up wireshark to check. I'm following a book so I'm not sure what's going wrong here and that's kinda my problem.